# Tor benchmark resources

Tags: bandwidth, performance

Are there any freely available resources for, or papers regarding Tor benchmarks?

I am specifically looking for things such as average number of circuit creation operations that a single onion-router can handle per second. Or the average bandwidth of an onion-router.

Answer (score 2):

You can find average bandwidth over time for each relay on [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) and [Globe](http://globe.rndm.de/).

Metrics on the network as a whole are here: https://metrics.torproject.org/

Answer (score 1):

The [Anonymity Bib](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/) contains some papers which deal which measurements of Tor. Maybe they can help you too.